# parted -s /dev/sdb resizepart doesnt work

Tags: partitioning

I am trying to resize the live/mounted volume on ubuntu 16.04. like (when run on command line)- 

`sudo parted /dev/sdb resizepart 2 Yes 275GB`

its giving me warning and ask for fix/ignore

```
Warning: Not all of the space available to /dev/sdb appears to be used, you can fix the GPT to use all of the space
(an extra 104857600 blocks) or continue with the current setting?
parted: invalid token: 2
Fix/Ignore?
Partition number?
```

I tried below all commands with -s option, but i was getting the warning and fix/ignore question

```
1. sudo parted -s /dev/sdb resizepart 2 100%
2. sudo parted -s /dev/sdb resizepart 2 275GB
3. sudo parted -s /dev/sdb resizepart 2 F 2 Y 275GB 
4. sudo parted -s /dev/sdb resizepart 2 Y 275GB
```

All these above commands gave me "fix/Ignore?". I used it in the script, but it fails to update the size. how can i avoid this in the shell script using "-s".

Is there any easy way to send the parameters in command line?

Comment: What do you mean by live, is it mounted?

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: yes, it is mounted. I m using ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: thanks George. yes my first time to ask question. Reframed it.

Comment: Please update your question wit the partition layout of /dev/sdb .. run `sudo parted /dev/sdb` in terminal, and then `p` on the parted prompt. And `q` to exit parted again.